# Is possible in Android to findView by String id?

Tags: android

Is possible in Android to findView by String Id?

I add some rows in table programmatically and in next iteration need to remove some of them and I have List id ( "tblRow_1", "tblRow_3" ..}). Can I retrieve by ids from the list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`getResources().getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the actual integer resource ID.

**example**

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(stringVar, "id", "com.sample.project");
view = findViewById(resID);
```

Comment: @Damir: Yup. Doable as shown above, but slow, and usually bad practice. There's usually a better software design that will let you avoid doing this sort of thing.

Comment: @kcoppock as is most types of reflection.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Resources.getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for this.